# Implementing Google OAuth 2.0 with Spring Boot and Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-oauth

How would I implement login only with Google OAuth. I do not want to store passwords and sensitive information (I would store email, name and profile photo ONLY) in my apps database (PostgreSQL).

Only specific people will have access to app, and I want them to login using google and that it checks if user has access.

I use Spring Boot for backend REST API, Angular for frontend, AWS for file storage and database and Gradle as build tool.

I watched some videos on youtube and read some articles on authentification in general but they weren't helpfull because they were not for my use case and used other tech stacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email, name and profile photo are all OpenID data. It is very likely that you don't have to store this in your own database (and save the burden of data synch when a user updates his Google profile). Saving user "subject" (`sub` claim which is immutable) should be enough.

Angular app should access OpenID data for currently authenticated user from ID token (not from your API).  ID token is part of the response when authenticating with authorization-code flow (provided that `openid` scope was requested, along with `email` and `profile` in your case).

Spring REST API should be able to query user data from Google API using client credentials flow.

Use [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) in your Angular app for users authentication, access & ID tokens acquisition and refreshing. This lib will also add access-token to all requests sent to configured routes: your resource-server will require it.

Configure your Spring REST API as a **resource-server**. [Tutorials there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) and use a REST client ready for client credentials flow to query Google API if needed (`@FeignClient`, `RestTemplate` and `WebClient` are widely used options with Spring)

### 2023 Update

[Spring Security team now discourages to use public OAuth2 clients](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390). As by using [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) we make the Single Page Application a public OAuth2 client, the solution above should not be applied anymore.

An alternative is to use a Backend For Frontend (a middleware on a server you trust) configured as a **confidential** client with login. requests from a browser to such a BFF are authorized with **sessions**. Only requests from the BFF to resource servers are authorized with tokens (stored in session).

`spring-cloud-gateway` is a perfect fit for such a BFF with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and the `TokenRelay` filter. **I wrote a [tutorial for that on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).**

Comment: How do I save users to database? Should I just store some kind of user id that Google provides? It will be restricted access, and I want to grant users access without registration (some kind of whitelist)

Comment: I updated: try not to save anything that can change and is already provided by Google. Just save `sub` claim which is an immutable key to your users data at Google.

Comment: Since I answered that (more than a year ago), Spring Security team has advised to use only confidential clients, which deprecated this solution (Angular app configured as public client with `angular-auth-oidc-client`). As an alternative, you should consider using a BFF. You might use `spring-cloud-gateway` configured with `TokenRelay` filter and as OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login`. Such a BFF could expose an endpoint returning the payload of the ID token in session.

Comment: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff#implementing-the-backend-for-frontend-pattern-with-spring-cloud-gateway